# flatten the Option part of a Future[Option[Option[T]]]

Tags: scala, concurrency

I have a `results: List[Future[Option[T]]]` which contains (parallel) calculations.

I want to obtain the first non-`None` result as soon as possible, or return `None` if all the calculations return `None`.

Currently, I'm doing this (which I consider to be ugly) to handle the case where `Future.find` doesn't find any results.

```
Future.find(results)(r => r.isDefined) map { 
  case Some(hit) => hit
  case _ => None
}
```

which will give me a `Future[Option[T]]` (what I want).

**Is there a cleaner way to obtain the `Future[Option[T]]`: i.e. without having to manually flatten `Future[Option[Option[T]]]`?**

Comment: Could you structure the computations within the Futures such that you could use `Future.firstCompletedOf` to get what you need?

Comment: @RandallSchulz not that I'm aware of... the computations may return `None` and I don't know which ones will do that (indeed, if I knew that in advance, I'd never start that computation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than specialise this to Options, you could write a general function such as:

```
def collectFirst[A, B](futures: List[Future[A]])(pfn: PartialFunction[A, B])
    (implicit ex: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[B]] =
  Future.find(futures)(pfn.isDefinedAt) map (_.collect(pfn))
```

In terms of this, you could rephrase your problem as:

```
collectFirst(results) { case Some(hit) => hit }
```

Comment: hmm, I don't like the use of `isDefinedAt` followed by a `collect` call to the same `pfn`.

Comment: It should be safe to replace `collect` with `map`, since if the inner result of `find` is a `Some`, we already know that `pfn` is defined for the value inside that.